# Is the Imperial officer in this short story supposed to be Tarkin?

Tags: star-wars

In the book *From a Certain Point of View,* there's a story titled "Of MSE-6 and  Men."  In this story, a stormtrooper has a brief affair with an unnamed Imperial officer.  It doesn't say specifically who this is, but I've seen people claiming that this officer is Tarkin.

Wookieepedia doesn't list the officer as Tarkin, but I know that's not a confirmed source of information.  Is there any actual confirmation in canon that this officer was Tarkin?

Comment: Since the story takes place aboard the Death Star during the events of *Ep. IV*, it makes no sense that it would be Tarkin.  Chatting with a lieutenant in a turbolift about random Stormtroopers, the state of a minor droid and how to prepare the interrogation droid?  That is _way_ below the pay grade of a Grand Moff.  Not to mention the unnamed officer wasn't even on the command bridge during the attack on Yavin IV...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Is it *confirmed* to be Tarkin?

**No.** The author doesn't name him in the text, nor has there been any confirmation from LucasFilm or Glen Weldon that it's him in the story.

### Was it *supposed* to be Tarkin?

All signs point to yes.

1. The voice actor,  Marc Thompson used in the audiobook is the same actor who portrays Tarkin in another story (doing the same accent).
2. The author has confirmed ([if](https://twitter.com/ghweldon/status/915734601104084992) [tangentially](https://twitter.com/ghweldon/status/916002354431893504)) that Tarkin is gay.